# Editted CSS dotted line

Tags: css

I'm new to CSS and was looking round the web to find a code to auto rezie images and the code i found is doing that perfectly. But the properly is, it reizes with some red dotted line around the image and when i try to edit, the whole image dissappears. can please someone help me out on how to get rid of the red dotted line while image shows up.

```
<style type="text/css">
#holder {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.tile {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: table;
}
.tile-layout {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.tile img {
    outline: 1px dashed red;
    width:100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: `outline: 1px dashed red;` this causes the red dotted line, if you don't want it, just remove it.

Comment: Just curious, what did you edit to try to get rid of the red line... that caused the entire image to disappear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the `outline` property :

```
<style type="text/css">
#holder {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.tile {
    padding: 10px 15px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    display: table;
}
.tile-layout {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.tile img {
    width:100%;
}
</style>
```

`outline` is a CSS2 property almost similar to the `border` one

Here is an article about that : http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/outline/

Comment: I wouldn't call a [16-year old CSS 2.0 property](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-CSS2-19980512/ui.html#dynamic-outlines) "new"

Comment: Lol... well it's not come with the first CSS specs... that what I meant >_>" I'll delete this word anyway. Thanks (ceci dit, ça fait toujours plaisir de se faire reprendre par qqun de chez Alsacréations)